Discard certain change from undolist
I usually want to delete empty spaces before the end of line, something than can be done easily with:
:%s/\s\+$//g|''

But honestly I would like to do not include this change in the undolist, possibly without loosing the previous undos in undolist...
A simple way to achieve it would be executing the above command, and the remove the last change from the undolist, but as far as I know it is not possible (really?), or better said I did not found any mention to this..
So is it possible to achieve this behavior?
PS: I am not using any undofile.

apart from doing :undojoin to join the change with a previous change, this is not possible. Or well, you can discard all your previous undo changes, but then you lose all your undo

OK, as far as I see, in this case :undojoin does not accomplish my needs. Thanks.

There is currently no way to programmatically alter the content of :help :undolist, which is pretty opaque anyway. Having several changes lumped in a single block while still being individually undoable is… not very helpful.
:help 'undolevels', which can be set to -1 to disable saving undos, actually nukes the whole undo list so it can't be used as a toggle either and :help :undojoin has been ruled out in the comments.
Maybe you could ask for a getundolist()/setundolist() combo on Vim's issue tracker and see what happens?

I've tried to save the undo history in a undofile, apply the change and then reloading the undofile but this doesn't work due to the undo algorithm.
